# SQL - Linked columns

Tags: sql, linker

I've run a query and it is showing in one column 'Status' specific characters for example 6 (See below)

```
**Name**        **start_time**                 **STATUS** 
Printing Group  2021-11-26 09:03:13.9400000     6   
Printing Group  2021-11-26 09:08:53.3560000     6
```

Anyone please tell me how I can find where I can find what status '6' or for some '5' is actually referring to?

Comment: No-one can help here without to see full DB structure. Look for tables named like %status%

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.